# “A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment: ” when running Java Project on JDK eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, dll, java-8, jvm

I am getting the following error when I run my Java project on Eclipse with JDK 8
This is the error:

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000180003990, pid=11244, tid=8800
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (15.0.2+7) (build 15.0.2+7-27)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (15.0.2+7-27, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, windows-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [rxtxSerial.dll+0x3990]
#
# No core dump will be written. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\iratx\eclipse-workspace\Mikros_b1\hs_err_pid11244.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
´´´
```

Comment: Nope, you are running with JDK 15

Comment: The logs shows you are actually running with Java 15. The log also shows the crash is in `rxtxSerial.dll` - which is part of a 3rd part serial comms library - is this something you are trying to use?